# Craft Commerce 1 - Stripe payment intents SCA ready

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, stripe

I am using Craft CMS 2 with Commerce 1.
I want to update to the new SCA ready (3d secure) Stripe integration.
Has anyone made this already?

Answer (score 1):

The Stripe for Commerce 2 plugin has been updated for SCA, but I'm not aware of any solution for Commerce 1.

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe